# Select box filled by json response using jquery and coldfusion

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

Let me preface this question.  I have just started using jquery, so please be kind.

I have searched for this answer, and I cannot seem to find anything that works, so I'm asking the question here.

I am going to have a page that contains a group of select  boxes that will populate a list of check boxes based on which option in the select is chosen.  I haven't got that far yet.  All I got so far is using the `$.ajax` to retrieve the data from the server. If I view the firebug console I see my JSON string.

```
{"DESCRIPTION":"Global Alpha I Benchmark","INCEPTION_DATE":"2004-02-29 00:00:00.0","DISCLOSURE":"","BENCHMARK_ID":"EBDVGA1INDEX"}
```

Here is the javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(':input:visible:enabled:first').focus();
    $(function(){
        $("select#benchmarks").change(function(){
            var formval = {benchmarks:$(this).val()}
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                data: formval,
                url: "request_processor.cfm",
                datatype: "json",
                success:$(function(response){alert(response);})

            });
        });
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<cfform name="testForm">
<div align="center" id="databox">
    <cfselect id="benchmarks" name="benchmarks" query="getBenchmarks" queryPosition="below" value="benchmark_id" display="benchmark_id">
        <option value="">Please Select an ID...</option>
    </cfselect>
    <cfselect id="myselect" name="myselect"></cfselect>
</div>
<div id="contentdiv"></div>
```

I have mucked something up, and now I can't even get data to show on the screen, so I don't know what to do.  Any help would be appreciated.  \

UPDATE:

@Rob

I have added the following to the success portion of the ajax call.

```
$.each(response,function(index){
options = "<option value='"+ response.description + "'>" + response.description + "</option>"
});
$("select#myselect").html(options);
```

Now nothing happens! No javascript error, no errors in the firebug console.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is.  Is your alert not coming up?  I expect it would alert you that response is an object, but not show any meaningful data.

Comment: Well, I guess I could have been more clear.  What I'm trying to do is create a series of check boxes, all with different values based on the selection from the select box.  As an intermediate step, I was just trying to create another select box with the data in the json.  I have been struggling trying to it to work, and I trying so many different things, I ended up screwing something else up, and I couldn't figure out what the problem was.

Comment: Try running a simple ajax call all by itself using datatype=text and see what response your getting from the json page. defining an error:function(msg){alert(msg);} in your ajax call might also help shed light on the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few issues with your "each" code.  First of all, based on your JSON string originally posted, you have a single object.  Unless you wrap it in `[]`, .each will iterate over each property, such as description and inception date.  If it's wrapped in brackets, it will iterate over it as if it is an array, once for each item in the collection.

So, assuming you pass it an array, your code should look like:

```
var options = '';
$.each(response, function(){
    options += "<option value='"+ this.DESCRIPTION + "'>" + this.DESCRIPTION + "</option>";
});
$("select#myselect").html(options);
```

I've made two changes.  First, I concatenate to the options string, so all options are collected.  I'm also using "this" to point to the correct item within the loop.

Edit:  I've also changed the case of DESCRIPTION.  I believe it's case-sensitive.

Comment: Here is the JSON now. `[{"DESCRIPTION":"Global Alpha I Benchmark","INCEPTION_DATE":"2004-02-29 00:00:00.0","DISCLOSURE":"","BENCHMARK_ID":"EBDVGA1INDEX"}]`.  The select `myselect` is now getting populated, but all values are undefined.

Comment: Also, I don't know if it's part of the problem, but I would stick with standard HTML elements rather than CF controls.  FORM instead of CFFORM, SELECT instead of CFSELECT.

Comment: Based on Rob's comment, does response contain a Javascript object or a JSON string?  Sounds like you're passing it the JSON string.  It should be a Javascript object that you are passing, not a string.

Comment: A, I can change the code around to use standard html, it still doesn't make sense, why `$.each` is looping through the JSON like it is a normal string, and added each character to `myselect` and that value is undefined

Comment: @RobM - As I mentioned before, it shouldn't be looping over the JSON at all.  Let's be clear about the difference between JSON and a Javascript object.  JSON is the string representation of a Javascript object, not the object itself.  You can try passing JSON.parse(response), but if you're doing it correctly on the server side you should be getting an object in your callback, not a string.

Comment: I added `response = JSON.parse(response) and it seems to be working.  I'm not sure why it was passing it as a string, but that seems to be corrected.  I have used JSON's before in support of a CF8 application, but currently I'm supporting a CF7 app, which doesn't have native support for JSONs.  I am using CFJSON.cfc to do the stringify. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

```
success:$(function(response){alert(response);})
```

should be

```
success:function(response){alert(response);}
```

$(function) is a shortcut for $(document).ready(function), so your not actually binding a real function for the ajax success callback.

Update:
just noticed you have another un-needed $()

```
$(function(){
  $("select#benchmarks").change(function(){
  ...
)
```

You are already inside a document ready event, there is no need to add another callback to document ready at this point.